# Socket.io room with most joined

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Well, title says it all. How can I get the rooms with most joined sockets? A way to list them ordered by sockets would be neat. Also if there is a way, how efficient is it? And if it isn't, can one make an own efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really tested, but I think this might work:

```
var roomNames = Object.keys(io.sockets.manager.rooms);
var sortedByNumberOfClients = roomNames.sort(function(room1, room2) {
  return io.sockets.manager.rooms[room2].length - io.sockets.manager.rooms[room1].length;
});
// sortedByNumberOfClients is an array of room names, sorted on
// number of clients in the room, largest room first.
```

I do believe that there's a default room with an empty string (`''`) as name that contains *all* clients, so you may want to skip that. Also, I think internally `socket.io` adds a leading `/` to each room name.

Comment: Would this return one room or more?

Comment: It's a list of all rooms currently active, sorted on number of clients in each room.